# How long does it generally take new releases to make it onto the snap network?

Tags: snap, versions

3 days ago PHPStorm posted that the newest major release is available, 2022.1: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/04/phpstorm-2022-1-release/

As an ubuntu user, my PHPStorm is managed by snapd.  It looks like the latest stable version on the snap network is still the previous version, 2021.3.3:

https://snapcraft.io/phpstorm

```
$ snap info phpstorm
name:      phpstorm
summary:   PhpStorm
publisher: jetbrains✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/phpstorm
contact:   https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/
license:   Proprietary
description: |
  PhpStorm is a PHP IDE that actually ‘gets’ your code. It supports PHP 5.3-7.2, provides on-the-fly
  error prevention, best autocompletion & code refactoring, zero configuration debugging, and an
  extended HTML, CSS, and JavaScript editor.
snap-id: qYt8GFdYX5B4J7mm6S6F4r4vAwnG5IgV
channels:
  latest/stable:    2021.3.3  2022-03-17 (260) 614MB classic
  latest/candidate: 2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  latest/beta:      2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  latest/edge:      2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  2022.1/stable:    –                                
  2022.1/candidate: 2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  2022.1/beta:      2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  2022.1/edge:      2022.1-RC 2022-04-08 (263) 670MB classic
  2021.3/stable:    2021.3.3  2022-03-17 (260) 614MB classic
  2021.3/candidate: 2021.3.3  2022-03-17 (260) 614MB classic
  2021.3/beta:      2021.3.3  2022-03-17 (260) 614MB classic
  2021.3/edge:      2021.3.3  2022-03-17 (260) 614MB classic
  2021.2/stable:    2021.2.4  2021-12-22 (248) 481MB classic
  2021.2/candidate: 2021.2.4  2021-12-22 (248) 481MB classic
  2021.2/beta:      2021.2.4  2021-12-22 (248) 481MB classic
  2021.2/edge:      2021.2.4  2021-12-22 (248) 481MB classic
  2021.1/stable:    2021.1.4  2021-06-30 (222) 475MB classic
  2021.1/candidate: 2021.1.4  2021-06-30 (222) 475MB classic
  2021.1/beta:      2021.1.4  2021-06-30 (222) 475MB classic
  2021.1/edge:      2021.1.4  2021-06-30 (222) 475MB classic
  2020.3/stable:    2020.3.3  2021-03-16 (208) 425MB classic
...
```

Oddly enough, there is an entry there for 2022.1/stable, but this row looks unlike the others with its "-"

While snap runs across linux distributions, I am guessing this is like any other distribution release situation: original source publishes release, then it takes a while for distributions/snap to do whatever they need to do to make said release available through their channels.

Is this how it works?  Does anyone have advice on how much of a delay I should generally expect?  I realize its unlikely anyone has the exact answer, but a ballpark would be helpful (couple days, couple weeks, couple months).

Comment: If you want to flip it to the newest release that is still a Release Candidate, you  run `sudo snap refresh phpstorm --candidate --classic` or you can wait until they push the newest version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I’m looking for the official stable release, which is out, though apparently not on snap yet.  But I will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Usually "days".

It depends upon the publisher of the Snap. It's reasonable to expect volunteer packagers to take a bit of time (days/weeks) to update a snap.

Let's see if that guideline is appropriate here.

```
$ snap info phpstorm | grep publisher
publisher: jetbrains*
$ snap info phpstorm | grep contact
contact:   https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/
```

In this case, the publisher of the Snap is the upstream project itself (not a volunteer packager). So it's appropriate for you to ask the full-time paid staff of Jetbrains about their plan and timeline.

There's also a second issue here: The snap channels. This particular snap has a "candidate" channel with the updated version (dated three days *before* the announcement of that Release Candidate!). So it does seem like Jetbrains isn't neglecting Snap users.

- Keep in mind that Linux users generally expect a fairly transparent QA/testing process, and that includes both Release Candidates and the testing of the Snap packaging.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the houghtful explanation.  I will reach out to JetBrains if I don’t see it up next week.  I appreciate the info.